# iPhone performance issue on successive view animations

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, animation

I am doing an iPhone application in which I have to show questions.Now the number of question is around 70 that will come one by one after the previous one is answered.The requirement is that I have to show animation like the question is coming on self.view from a different view.When I called animation around 70 times for all my question on interval of 3 seconds per question the movement of view became slightly slower each time on repeated calling.Until 20 questions passed its hard to find something wrong is happening but after that we can sense the difference in speed.

I tried to use UITableview in case of view along with animation and each time I deleted the Table when the question is answered and simultaneously creating a new one with new question.This worked a little better than view but still we can sense the difference in speed with which table is coming after animation with new question.

**Any Suggestions.**

**Edit:** When question is answered at that time table is on the screen.Just after answering I am setting the view frame like this:

```
[TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(320,49, 320, 411)];
```

Then again I have to take the table in full screen.Then I am using this after two seconds:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,49, 320, 411)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Then it looks like question is coming from other view.In this course of time after some question the speed seems to be decreasing.

Please **suggest a better way** to do the same.

Comment: It's not clear how you create/destroy the views, but maybe a better approach is to have one strong view only to animate, and change it's content each time.

Comment: How are you 1) doing the animations? 2) managing the views?

Comment: Please add code if you can. It's not clear how you implement the anumations and view changes.

Comment: I am doing animations each time in slots to 3 seconds.Moving the same view with animations only.

Comment: I think you are suffering from `Memory` issue. Have you noticed any `Memory Warning` ? If yes than you need to do `Memory Mangement`.

Comment: What I want to ask successive call to animation can also lead to memory warning?

Comment: No. I think successive call to animation can not lead to memory warning but as you explained you are creating new UITableView for every question , I think performance issue can be due to it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to animate those all views in one animation block. Having 70 animation blocks runnig at the same will slow your app, try to do all 70 view animations in one animation block, you will see the boost.

How can i do that? you can say.

Maybe you can create a singleton and pass all the view animations there, keep them in a property or something, then by giving a [mySingleton start]; command, you can execute all the animations in one block. Or you may figure out a better and easy solution, the code is yours :)